# UIWebView content too small when enable zooming

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

In UIWebView if I enable scalesPageToFit the content seems too small
not like if I disable it.
I want to make content not very small at first but also enable zoom

[image]

!enter image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAu3w.png)